# Can I protect github branch with require pull request but without required review?

Tags: git, github

Is there an option to protect a GitHub branch from direct pushes (not force push necessarily), with require pull request but without the need of at least one review?

In my team we are using a "dev" branch for our latest code changes.
But being its a dev branch, I don't want to review every non-significance PR.

I think this is a good practice for building a stronger self discipline within our team.
And also it will prettify our git history by reducing the many "small fix" or "missing file" commits.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, q.v. here: https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to protect against all pushes, not only force push.